# How to get the Winform program run time?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, quartz.net

I am using quartz.net to close the machine in supermarket,when at 22：00.Trigger the shutdown event:

```
        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {               
            logger.Info("shutdown.....");
            try
            {
                StatusHelper.ShutdownComputerImpl(MachineOperType.Shutdown);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.Error("Shutdown computer encount an error", e);
            }
        }
```

But the quartz.net will trigger the job when first time run!!!!

So I could get the system already run how much time, if less than 10 minutes, the function could not be execute.Like this:

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
            {               
                logger.Info("shutdown.....");
                try
                {
                     if(GetCurrentProcessRuntime()>50)
                     {
                         StatusHelper.ShutdownComputerImpl(MachineOperType.Shutdown);
                     }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    logger.Error("Shutdown computer encount an error", e);
                }
            }
```

I am programming in C# Winform,visual studio 2013,and i want to get the program run time from start,how to get it?May be the program run 2 hours,and the time will more than 2 hour(or minutes).

I am not measure the code run how much time,I want to get system run time from start!!!

Comment: You can use `Stopwatch` class to measure this time. Try something first, show people your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using stopwatch class:

```
using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Create new stopwatch
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    // Begin timing
    stopwatch.Start();

    // Do something     

    // Stop timing
    stopwatch.Stop();

    // Write result
    Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}",
        stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to using the same stopwatch in different class,and different namespace?

Comment: You can try to create static class with Stopwatch.